# Issue with using tensorflow.metrics.recall_at_thresholds

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been trying to use the recall_at_thresholds function in TensorFlow. The steps I am doing are as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0])
b = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.9], [0.1, 0.9], [0.3, 0.7])
c = tf.metrics.recall_at_thresholds(a,b,[0.5])
with sess as tf.Session():
    print(sess.run(c))
```

However, on running this, I get the following:

```
2017-11-08 16:14:03.914462: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value recall_at_thresholds/true_positives
     [[Node: recall_at_thresholds/true_positives/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@recall_at_thresholds/true_positives"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](recall_at_thresholds/true_positives)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 789, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 997, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1132, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1152, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value recall_at_thresholds/true_positives
     [[Node: recall_at_thresholds/true_positives/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@recall_at_thresholds/true_positives"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](recall_at_thresholds/true_positives)]]
     [[Node: recall_at_thresholds/Cast/_1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_33_recall_at_thresholds/Cast", tensor_type=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'recall_at_thresholds/true_positives/read', defined at:
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py", line 2059, in recall_at_thresholds
labels, predictions, thresholds, weights, includes=('tp', 'fn'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py", line 514, in _confusion_matrix_at_thresholds
true_p = _create_local('true_positives', shape=[num_thresholds])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py", line 196, in _create_local
validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1679, in variable
caching_device=caching_device, name=name, dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 200, in __init__
expected_shape=expected_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 319, in _init_from_args
self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1303, in identity
result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Identity", input=input, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value recall_at_thresholds/true_positives
     [[Node: recall_at_thresholds/true_positives/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@recall_at_thresholds/true_positives"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](recall_at_thresholds/true_positives)]]
     [[Node: recall_at_thresholds/Cast/_1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_33_recall_at_thresholds/Cast", tensor_type=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]`
```

I am relatively new to Tensorflow, and the error message is a bit intimidating to me. Could anyone let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0]])
b = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.9], [0.1, 0.9], [0.3, 0.7]])
c = tf.metrics.recall_at_thresholds(a, b, [0.5])
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
  print(sess.run(c))
```

The issue is that `recall_at_thresholds` creates local variables as stated in its [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/recall_at_thresholds). TensorFlow variables need to be initialized. The `sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())` line does this.